# EasyAdmin 3 - Generate URL for redirect in controller (no crud)

Tags: symfony, easyadmin3

I have made a controller (not a crud) with this extension :

```
class ScanController extends AbstractDashboardController
```

In this controller, I have a process with more steps and for each step I have create a action :

```
    /**
     * @Route("/scan/step1", name="scan_step1")
     */
    public function step1(Request $request, EntityManagerInterface $entityManager): Response
    {
}

    /**
     * @Route("/scan/step2/{id_scan}", name="scan_step2")
     */
    public function step2(int $id_scan, Request $request, EntityManagerInterface $entityManager): Response
    {
}
```

In my dashboard menu config I have add a menu to the first step :

```
MenuItem::linktoRoute('Scan', 'fa fa-barcode', 'scan_step1'),
```

The url of the Step1 is :

```
https://xxx/admin?menuIndex=2&routeName=scan_step1&signature=WeCEAS5-LhXL1Zy50HTVPuFjUpDKc7K0vdBLUY-T45E&submenuIndex=1
```

And this is ok but now, when I have done in the step1, I want to redirect the customer to the Step2 and I have used the simple "redirectToRoute" function :

```
    return $this->redirectToRoute('scan_step2', [
        'id_scan'=>$scan->getId(),
    ]);
```

But when the page is open, I don't have any menu any more....I'm in the template but "outside" the easyadmin "world"
and the URL is now :

```
https://xxxx/scan/step2/14
```

I'm sure that I need to generate by redirect URL with a easyadmin function but I dont find the way to make this :-(
Is it the AdminUrlGenerator and something else and how ?

Answer (score 0):

I have find the solution.
First I extend with EasyAdminController :

```
class ScanController extends EasyAdminController
{  
}
```

and for the redirection :

```
    $url = $this->adminUrlGenerator
    ->setRoute('scan_step2',[
        'id_scan'=>$scan->getId(),
    ])
    ->generateUrl();

    return $this->redirect($url);
```

And Everything is fine now.